# Q: How can I combine these two foreach loop

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach, simple-html-dom

I have a simple html dom query which read informations from a football fixtures source, and I loading also a json source.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ini_set("user_agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17");

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$str = file_get_contents('general.json');

$json = json_decode($str,true);

$filename = "source.html";
$html = file_get_html($filename);

class matches {
    var $day;
    var $kickofftime;
    var $result;

    function matches ($day, $kickofftime, $tip){
       $this->day=$day;
       $this->kickofftime=$kickofftime;
       $this->result=$result;
       return $this;
    }
}


$i=0;

$day=$html->find('h1',0);
$day->plaintext;
$day=str_replace("<h1>TODAY FOOTBALL FIXTURES: ","", $day);
$day=str_replace("</h1>","", $day);
$matchday = str_replace(array('MONDAY ', 'TUESDAY ', 'WEDNESDAY ', 'THURSDAY ', 'FRIDAY ',  'SATURDAY ',  'SUNDAY '), '', $day);
$matchday=str_replace(" ","-", $matchday);
$matchday=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($matchday));

foreach($html->find('table.fixtures') as $matches) 
{

    foreach ($matches->find('tr[class=a1],tr[class=a2]') as $matchesTR) {

        $kickofftime=$matchesTR->find('td[class=a11],td[class=a21]',0)->plaintext;
        $kodate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$matchday $kickofftime +1 hour"));
        $result=$matchesTR->find('td');

        echo $kodate;
        echo $result[6]->plaintext.'<br>' ; 

        $i++;


    }
}

//Here is the 2nd foreach with the data of JSON source:

foreach($json as $key => $value) {

    $value = json_decode($value, true);
    echo $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "  " . $value["club"] . "<br>";
}

// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);

?>
```

The current results from the simple html dom html source:

**2014-12-23 20:00:00 2-1

2014-12-23 11:00:00 3-1

2014-12-26 08:00:00 1-1**

The result from the JSON source:

**America Copa America Boca Juniors

Europe Bundesliga Hannover

Asia JLeague Nagoya**

I would like to combine these two results in one foreach and I would like to get this result:

**2014-12-23 20:00:00 2-1 America Copa America Boca Juniors

2014-12-23 11:00:00 3-1 Europe Bundesliga Hannover

2014-12-26 08:00:00 1-1 Asia JLeague Nagoya**

I hope that there is some expert who can help for me because I tried a lot of variation but without result. I got some advice (with code) from experts, but there was everytime errors. With my code there is no error, but I need other solution because I would like to put all variables to one foreach. Many thanks, I hope that somebody could help me with code, because I am not on high level at php. Thanks again!

I would like to put the two foreach into one foreach, but I don't want to create a new array because I not need.

Comment: What associates two datasets with each other? Are values related solely based on their indices in each array (i.e. the first element in the first array goes with the first element of the second array, the second element goes with the second element, etc.)?

Comment: the sequence is totally same, html source (it is a table with fixtures) row 1 is the pair of the json first item, html source row 2. is the pair of the json second item.  Just the date of the kickoff time is parsed from the title of the html table, it is important I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I concatenate two arrays with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473851/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-with-php)

Comment: Yes, I see that there is similar questions, but I can't use array maps because I am not on high level

Comment: And I not need to put these two arrays into one array, I would like to put the variables into one foreach loop!

Comment: What do you mean by high level? I'd say that use of the [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function is less complex than the code you've already written. It may just take a little experimentation and some trust in your own competency. If you don't want to create a combined array, use the key from one array to output the associated value from the other array. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: thanks for the good words, but I know my level. I will probably try to do, but I think I am not so high level that needs for the use of array_map function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will always have the same amount of items in each and that they match 1 to 1, 2 to 2, you can do this:

```
$htmlDates = array();
$jsonLeag = array();

foreach($html->find('table.fixtures') as $matches) {
    foreach($matches->find('tr[class=a1],tr[class=a2]') as $matchesTR) {
        $kickofftime=$matchesTR->find('td[class=a11],td[class=a21]',0)->plaintext;
        $kodate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$matchday $kickofftime +1 hour"));
        $result=$matchesTR->find('td');

        //echo $kodate;
        //echo $result[6]->plaintext.'<br>' ;
        $htmlDates[] = $kodates;
    }
}

//Here is the 2nd foreach with the data of JSON source:

foreach($json as $key => $value) {
    $value = json_decode($value, true);
    //echo $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "  " . $value["club"] . "<br>";
    $jsonLeag[] = $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "  " . $value["club"];
}

if(count($htmlDates) < count($jsonLeag)){
    for($i=0;$i<count($htmlData);$i++){
        echo $htmlData[$i] . " " . $jsonLeag[$i] . "<br />\r\n";
    }
} else {
    for($i=0;$i<count($jsonLeag);$i++){
        echo $htmlData[$i] . " " . $jsonLeag[$i] . "<br />\r\n";
    }
}
```

Since you have the nested list first and nothing ties the two data sets together, there is no simple way to run one loop and get the data from both. It's easier to push the data you want into an array for each set, and then walk both arrays with one counter. The **caveat** here is that if one has an extra element, you will get missing results or errors.

Comment: Your code is good, but I would like to use later the variables at mysql database, so I think assign all values (like country, competition, club) into one array is not good for me because how can I add to mysql if them assigned to one array

Answer (score 0):

Save keys of json arrays and use the next in each loop.

```
$json_keys = array_keys($json);
$i_key = 0;
foreach($html->find('table.fixtures') as $matches) 
{

    foreach ($matches->find('tr[class=a1],tr[class=a2]') as $matchesTR) {

        $kickofftime=$matchesTR->find('td[class=a11],td[class=a21]',0)->plaintext;
        $kodate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$matchday $kickofftime +1 hour"));
        $result=$matchesTR->find('td');

        echo $kodate;
        echo $result[6]->plaintext.
        $value = json_decode($json[$json_keys[$i_key++]], true);
        echo $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "  " . $value["club"] . "<br>";
        $i++;
    }
}

// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

There are many other variants - use array_shift(),  next()... I've written the first come in mind